# Is 搏杀 used in jest in 今年剩下一个星期了，继续努力搏杀?

Tags: word-choice, usage

In December, I read this in a social network post:

> 今年剩下一个星期了，继续努力搏杀！

In English slang, one might say "killing it" to mean performing well. Is this use of `搏杀` figurative, literal, or humorous?

Comment: What do mean by "剩翻"? Shouldn't it be "剩下"? At least in madarin, it should be "今年就剩下一个星期了，继续努力搏杀！"

Comment: I think it is from 广东 province.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be figurative, means "working hard".